# image plots with color key legends in layout

Tags: r, plot, layout

I want to make plots arranged like this, but with color key legends.

```
layout(matrix(c(1,1,2,3,2,3),2,3))
y <- matrix(1:200,10,20)
par(mai=c(0.9,0.9,0.1,0.1))
plot(1,1)
par(mai=c(0.6,0.6,0.1,0.8))
image(y)
image(y)
```

The problem with this code is that the image plots do not have a color key legend. `image.plot` can make the legend, but `image.plot` does not work with `layout`. This question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47450326/use-of-image-plot-with-specific-layout) but has not been answered.

```
layout(matrix(c(1,1,2,3,2,3),2,3))
y <- matrix(1:200,10,20)
par(mai=c(0.9,0.9,0.1,0.1))
plot(1,1)
par(mai=c(0.6,0.6,0.1,0.8))
library(fields)    
image.plot(y)
image.plot(y)
```

I tried to make a legend with `addLegend`,

```
layout(matrix(c(1,1,2,3,2,3),2,3))
y <- matrix(1:200,10,20)
par(mai=c(0.9,0.9,0.1,0.1))
plot(1,1)
par(mai=c(0.6,0.6,0.1,0.8))
library(fields)
image(y,col=hcl.colors(12, "RdYlBu", rev = TRUE))
addLegend(setupLegend(), col=hcl.colors(12, "RdYlBu", rev = TRUE), zlim = c(0,200))
image(y,col=hcl.colors(12, "RdYlBu", rev = TRUE))
addLegend(setupLegend(), col=hcl.colors(12, "RdYlBu", rev = TRUE), zlim = c(0,200))
```

but it still has problems. I like to make the plots without using ggplot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`color.legend` worked fine.

```
layout(matrix(c(1,1,2,3,2,3),2,3))
y <- matrix(1:200,10,20)
par(mai=c(0.9,0.9,0.1,0.1))
plot(1,1)
par(mai=c(0.6,0.6,0.1,0.6))
library(fields)
library(plotrix)

image(y,col=hcl.colors(12, "RdYlBu", rev = TRUE))
color.legend(1.1,0,1.15,1,c(1,100,200),hcl.colors(12, "RdYlBu", rev = TRUE),gradient="y",align="rb")
image(y,col=hcl.colors(12, "RdYlBu", rev = TRUE))
color.legend(1.1,0,1.15,1,c(1,100,200),hcl.colors(12, "RdYlBu", rev = TRUE),gradient="y",align="rb")
```